# set default color model for color palette

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

In Illustrator's Swatch palette's options, my swatches are set to color type: `process color`, color mode: `rgb`, and they're `global`.  Whenever I click these swatches and they're displayed in the color palette, the color model always defaults to Pantone, where I want it to be hsb.  I'd like to know if the color mode I select can somehow persist, because whenever I select another swatch, the color palette reverts back to displaying the color as a Pantone.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to set this as a default with the current Illustrator version.

You can change the document color model to either `RGB` or `CMYK`, but `HSB` isn't technically a *"color model"*, but is more of an abstraction.

There are a few workarounds you can try to streamline your workflow.

1. A "saving time" way to do this, is to  click on the Color Spectrum Bar while holding down the Shift button.
   This will change the color scheme between all of them.

[image]

2. Another solution if you are working with gradients would be to 
   Set the 'Color' panel to HSB mode.

   Keep the 'Color' panel and 'Gradient' panel both in view.

   Now, when you click a color on your gradient spectrum, you can modify the color with HSB model in the 'Color' panel. (This means no need to double-click the gradient color swatch that annoyingly opens to default RGB color picker

[image]